# Tinymce add additional words to existing translation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce, translation

We use tinymce in a rails application using two gems:

Using tinymce-rails 5.8.2
Using tinymce-rails-langs 5.20200505

We would like to add some additional translations of individual words and change a couple without disturbing the rest.  Is that possible?  In config/tinymce.yml we have 'setup: tinyMceSetup' so I added a line at the bottom of app/views/javascripts/tinymce_setup.js.erb where tinyMceSetup is defined: "`tinymce.util.I18n.add('es',{"Line height": "Altura de la L\u00ednea"})`" , thinking that that would add just the desired translation but it adds it and wipes out everything else.

Checking the documentation for tinymce I can't find a way to access the translation hash and just change a single key:value pair.  Maybe someone knows a way to do it or has another method that will work for us?  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You've got the right idea to be able to add translations programmatically. The problem however is that if translations are added before the `ScriptsLoaded` event is fired then it'll appear as if the translations are already loaded and won't attempt to load them. As such, the `setup` function in combination with the `ScriptsLoaded` event can be used like so to add additional custom translations programatically:

```js
setup: function(editor) {
  editor.on('ScriptsLoaded', function() {
    tinymce.addI18n('es',{"Line height": "Altura de la L\u00ednea"});
  });
}
```

Note: `tinymce.addI18n` is just an alias for `tinymce.util.I18n.add`.